# Is it possible to access children of an object w/out knowing the parent?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object:

```
[
    {"ML":[
        {"TeamName":"Team 1","League":"League 1"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 2","League":"League 2"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 3","League":"League 3"}
    ]},
    {"3A":[
        {"TeamName":"Team 4","League":"League 1"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 5","League":"League 2"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 6","League":"League 3"}
    ]},
    {"2A":[
        {"TeamName":"Team 7","League":"League 1"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 8","League":"League 2"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 9","League":"League 3"}
    ]}
]
```

How can I access `"TeamName"` for each group without specifying the parent (e.g. `"ML"`)?

Normally, it's `ML.TeamName`, is possible to do something like `x.TeamnName`?

The reason for this is that the group names are dynamic and unpredictable.

I basically want to iterate through the groups (parent groups w/ children set within them). Think of it as creating an `<ul>` for each group (w/ name of the group as the title) and list of children in `<li>` that has value of "TeamName".

I'm using jQuery and want results like this:

```
<h4>ML</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Team 1</li>
  <li>Team 2</li>
  <li>Team 3</li>
</ul>

<h4>3A</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Team 4</li>
  <li>Team 5</li>
  <li>Team 6</li>
</ul>

<h4>2A</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Team 7</li>
  <li>Team 8</li>
  <li>Team 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What result are you looking for? A set of team names or a single name?

Comment: Sure, but which one do you want if you say `x.TeamName`? ML, 3A or 2A? There is a reason they have key values... that way you know which one you are talking about.  Of course you could always loop over them and then do something with each of them.

Comment: You could get all the parents and loop through them...

Comment: I basically want to iterate through the groups (parent groups w/ children set within them). Think of it as creating an `<ul>` for each group (w/ name of the group as the title) and list of children in `<li>` that has value of `"TeamName"`.

Comment: @DrCord can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: `See comments for more info.` Please, instead of adding information on comments, edit the question to add any extra information.

Comment: This seems like a poorly designed data structure. Why have an object with just a single, variable-named property? Instead of the array, you should have an object whose property names are all the keys.

Comment: @Barmer I don't have control of the data structure that the server sends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is stored in `data`, you can use ES5 [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
data.Result.map(function(obj){
    for(var i in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        return obj[i].map(function(obj){
            return obj.TeamName
        });
});
```

Or simplifying with ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions):

```
data.Result.map(obj => {
    for(var i in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        return obj[i].map(obj => obj.TeamName);
});
```

With small modifications, you can get those html (note it's vulnerable to html injection)

```
wrapper.innerHTML += data.Result.map(obj => {
    for(var i in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        return '<h4>'+i+'</h4>\n'
            + obj[i].map(obj => '\t<li>'+obj.TeamName+'</li>\n').join('');
}).join('');
```

This way isn't vulnerable:

```
data.Result.forEach(obj => {
    for(var i in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var h4 = document.createElement('h4'),
            ul=document.createElement('ul');
        h4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        wrapper.appendChild(h4);
        obj[i].forEach(obj => {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.TeamName));
            ul.appendChild(li);
        });
        wrapper.appendChild(ul);
        return;
    }
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I should look into ES5/ES6, looks interesting. `result` is actually an array of objects, how do I store it in `data`? Is there a way to decide where the html will be injected (like a jQuery append)? Let say I want to append it to `<div class="content"></div>`.

Comment: @Steve If you want to replace `data`, you can just use `data = data.Result.map(/* ... */)`. The html will be injected to `wrapper`.

Comment: my problem was that I had the data in array of objects like: `console.log(results)` shows `[obj1, obj2, obj3]` and when using your code, I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >` when using `results.forEach(...` I've update my question above.

Comment: @Steve That may be because your browser doesn't support ES6 arrow functions (sadly only Firefox supports it currently). Try replacing `obj => {` with `function(obj){`.

Comment: went with another solution, but your code looks like it's the correct answer for a browser that support ES6. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation:

```
Result["ML"].TeamName
```

If you want to know everything in the list

```
var result = JSON.parse(...);

for (var i = 0; i < result.Result.length; i++) {
  console.log(result.Result[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the goal is to *eliminate* the extra level and flatten the teams, consider the following ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed5jU/)). It uses basic looping, but hopefully shows the deconstruction process.

```
var results = json.Result;
var teams = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   var conf = results[i];
   // conf will be like {ML: ..}
   for (var p in conf) {
       // Enumerate properties, p is "ML", etc. In the given JSON there
       // will only be one property to enumerate.
       if (conf.hasOwnProperty(p)) {               
           var confTeams = conf[p];
           // confTeams is like [{TeamName:..},..]
           teams = teams.concat(confTeams)
       }
   }
};
```

Now `teams` contains transformed data like:

```
[ {"TeamName":"Team 1","League":"League 1"},
  {"TeamName":"Team 2","League":"League 2"},
  .. ]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I actually still need them in group. I added extra details to my question for clarification.

Comment: @Steve If they are still needed in a group see Oriol's answer and/or just do the processing as-is (e.g. modify the loops above to immediately process the value without returning a flattened form).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library like lodash or underscore

if you don't need to know the original key...

```
var list = _.reduce(j.Result,function(c,v,i,l){
  return c.concat(_.values(v)[0]);
},[])
```

if you want to index the original key inside the objects...

```
var list = _.reduce(j.Result,function(c,v,i,l){
  return c.concat(_.map(_.values(v)[0],function(vv,ii){
    vv.key = _.keys(v)[0]
    return vv; // change each object here
  }));
},[]);

console.log(list)
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/liqin/2/edit)